# Statechange on Refresh in History.js

Tags: javascript, html, history.js

I'm using history.js to manipulate the HTML5 browser history API, and everything works as expected except when the page is refreshed.

When the page is initially loaded by the browser, the `statechange` event is fired thus triggering my custom `statechange` logic. However, this event is not fired when the page is refreshed by the user (e.g., presses `F5` or clicks the reload button in their browser).

Is there any way to force a `statechange` even when the browser is refreshed, or am I looking at this problem all wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what was causing the issue, but this little code "fixed" the issue

```
$(function()
{
    if (History.getCurrentIndex() == 0)
    {
         History.Adapter.trigger(window, 'statechange');
    }
});
```

Comment: hi, I am also using this plugin but not able to solve a issue. Please see if you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21910467/1211329